# Unable to use multiple switch case - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have data like this:

[image]

I need to get for each item if sales is compared with threshold and decide "achieved" or "not-achieved". If not achieved how many days remaining to reach threshold.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    ItemDate,
    DATEADD(dd, -(DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, ItemDate))), 
               DATEADD(mm,1,ItemDate)) DateEndOfMonth,
    DATEDIFF(d, ItemDate, DATEADD(dd, -(DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, ItemDate))), 
    DATEADD(mm, 1, ItemDate))) AS DaysRemainingm,
    ItemSales,  
    Logical_opr = CASE Opr   
                     WHEN 'less than' THEN '<'  
                     WHEN 'greater than' THEN '>'  
                     ELSE ''  
                  END,
    Threshold  
FROM
    itemData
```

Here is fiddle where am playing around to achieve  --> [link here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c8f52/23/0)

I'm stuck here. Please suggest how I can achieve my goal

Comment: Hi there mehdi! One quick question: how do you want to compute the days remaining to reach the threshold?

Comment: @ACC suppose date is 2020-07-29 and sales is 20.. but threshold of that month is 50.  SO the end date of the month is 2020-07-31.. so if i do diff from date and calculated end date, am getting 2 days remaining to achieve 30 (i.e 50-20 ) sales.

Comment: Use [searched CASE expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), like `case when opr = 'less than' and sales <= threshold then 'achieved'...`

Comment: How much effort do you "save" writing `DATEADD(dd` vs `DATEADD(day` ? And which is more readable? And you add difficulty by using both "d" and "dd" for "day".

Comment: @SMor am new to this... next time i will keep in mind

Answer (score 0):

Your working query columns doesn't seem to match your description of requirements, however does the following work for you?

```
with t as (
    select *, 
    case when opr='less than' then 
        case when itemsales < threshold then 'Not a' else 'A' end
    else
        case when itemsales < threshold then 'Not a' else 'A' end
    end + 'chieved' Result,
    DateDiff(day,itemdate,EOMonth(itemdate)) Remaining
    from itemData
)
select Id, Itemdate, ItemSales, Threshold, Result, 
    case Result when 'Achieved' then 0 else Remaining end Remaining
from t
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c8f52/35)

Comment: Thank you @Stu,  Yes. but for achieved i don't want remaining days. it can be '0' for achieved

Comment: @mehdi I have tweaked the query, is that now what you require?

Comment: Thanks @Stu, if i want to exclude weekends (i.e saturday and sunday)

Comment: @mehdi Do I detect some goalpost chasing, that's not in your question. You can add `where datename(weekday, itemdate) not in ('saturday','sunday')